# How to cancel one http request when we have multiple requests in process?

Tags: angularjs

Please refer http://embed.plnkr.co/52wwQh7iv88JtwJpANQ3/. In the plunker,we have a button which will add a widget once we click it and make a service call. Each widget is having a cancel icon. If a user clicks the button n time, we have "n" number of widget and a service request for each. When all the requests are in progress, i want to cancel one widget and the request associated with it. I tried using timeout property in service, but it is cancelling all the requests which are in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [canceling $http Requests in AngularJS example](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx) explained in nice and simple way. I think it suits your requirements.

Comment: Request URL in given article is having id which is being used to  uniquely identify each call. But in my case, endpoint is same.@M. Stefanczuk